# Why do I need to build my C# project (which references an F# project) twice for it to work?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, f#, msbuild

I've got a C# project that references an F# project in the same solution. If I build the solution, it fails with something like `Metadata file '(path-to-my-fsharp-project-dll)' could not be found` (error code CS0006). If I simply build it again, the build succeeds.

If I clean the solution from Visual Studio and build again, it succeeds as well. I need to clean it completely with `git clean -fxd` for it to start failing again when I try to build it.

Also, if I build the F# project first and then the C# project, the build succeeds.

In addition to the error, there are also a bunch of warnings of the form `The referenced component '(component)' could not be found`, where the components are all of the referenced assemblies by my C# project. In my case, these are

- System.Data
- System.ValueTuple
- System.Xml.Linq
- nunit.framework
- System.Xml
- Microsoft.CSharp
- System
- System.Data.DataSetExtensions
- System.Core

It's very surprising that assemblies such as "System" can't be found given that other projects find them just fine.

Comment: What does VS show for the build order in the solution? (Look at Project | Project Build Order.)

Comment: @Richard It shows the right order. However, the "Dependencies" was wrong. The C# project did not have a dependency on the F# project (I wonder why). Once I created that dependency by clicking on the checkbox, the build worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Most likely VS added a reference to the F# project dll instead of a project reference.

Compare the references to the C# projects and the F# project in your csproj. If you add the F# project as a project reference instead of a dll include, VS will automatically build the F# project when needed.

Comment: I thought I added the F# project as a project reference. To make sure, I deleted the current reference and re-added it as a project reference. The dependency was made and built properly. However, when I cleaned by repo and looked at the project dependency, it was not there any more, so the build failed. It seems like the only way it would work is if I manually make the dependency.

Comment: Can you share your csproj?